# Dynamic table pivot on store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, pivot

I'm doing a web interface to bind objects to users. I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

It is object of a different kind. I have a desire to display a table dynamically in SQL to avoid doing it in PHP (which would be cumbersome and time to be displayed).

I explain a bit of my data model.

I have modules (Module Table) that have features (Feature Table). The features are so an inventory object that will bind them and a user. To make an inventory of an object functionality, I need a form and this form has fields (Table Field). These fields will have data that will be inserted in the " DataField " table. ID " id_group " allows grouping field values ​​from the same form.

Until then, no worries. My problem comes when I want to show that I linked in my values ​​of my fields with a user.

If I take the example of the "Mobile" module. It has three features "Number" which includes the mobile phone numbers , "Device" which includes the mobile phone models and "Link" that will allow me to bind a number ( "Number" ) with mobile ( "Devices" ) and users ( "User" ) .

Functionality "Number" has the fields : "Short Number ", "Long Number" and "External Number"

Functionality "Device" has the fields " Manufacturer " and " Model" .

You can see data related to the "Number" feature :

```
ID |Short Number|Long Number|External Number|
1  | 4545       | 3314545   | 0101014545    |
2  | 1234       | 3311234   | 0101011234    |
3  | 9876       | 3319876   | 0101019876    |
```

You can see data related to the "Device" feature:

```
ID |Manufacture|Device|
4  | Alcatel   | 4018 | 
5  | Alcatel   | 4028 | 
6  | Cisco     | 7676 |
```

Tables I just see, I can get in with a SQL stored procedure that retrieves me the names of fields and added my column then shows me the data horizontally.

Then I made ​​a connection to a number (Number) with a model (Devices) and a user (Users) in R_Data_Field_User table. It is here that I can not see my picture. Here's what I'd like to get dynamically depending on the module and functionality:

```
ID_LINK | User     | Number                    | Device         |
1       | 1 Romain | 1 4545 3314545 0101014545 | 4 Alcatel 4018 |
2       | 2 Jean   | 2 1234 3311234 0101011234 | 5 Alcatel 4028 |
3       | 3 Pierre | 3 9876 3319876 0101019876 | 5 Alcatel 4028 |
```

I wish to make a stored procedure that spring me this table. I think we need only variable as the Feature ID

[Here is my SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2c47)

I hope I was clear ...

I continued my research ...